# finding the values of a and b(real numbers) that makes the function differentiable at any point of its domain

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, parametric, piecewise-continuity

I'm given this function:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
(lnx)^4  & 0<x< e \\
ax+b & x≥e
\end{cases}
$$

and I'm asked for which real values of 'a' and 'b' the function is differentiable at any point

I understand that for every x≠1 the function is differentiable.

and now I'm trying the find the values of 'a' and 'b' that make the function differentiable at x=e

this is what I did so far:

first I demanded that the function will be Continuous at x=e, meaning I demand that

$\lim\limits_{x \to e^{-}} f(x)
= \lim\limits_{x \to e^{+}} f(x) = f(e)$

and I got the equation:
$ae+b = e$

next, I demanded that the function will be differentiable at x = e,
I demanded that

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^{-}} \frac{f(e+h)-f(e)}{h}
= \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{f(e+h)-f(e)}{h}$

so far I got:
$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{f(e+h)-f(e)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{(a(e+h)+b) - (ae+b)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{(ae+ah+b) - (ae+b)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{ah}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{+}} a = a$

but when I tried to calculate $\lim\limits_{h \to 0^{-}} \frac{f(e+h)-f(e)}{h}$ I got stuck, so far I got

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^{-}} \frac{f(e+h)-f(e)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0^{-}} \frac{(ln(e+h))^4 - (ae+b)}{h} = ???$

now I don't know how to solve this, I'll be glad of any help you can give me,

should I calculate the derivative function at $0<x<e$ and at $x>e$ using the chain rule and then demand that $f'(1+) = f'(1-)  $
or should I stick to the limit definition of the derivative?

Comment: Limit definition is a good practice, if you know how to derive chain rule and the derivative of $\ln x$ from the limit definition, then you can manage to derive it in your OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your continuity condition: it should be $ae+b=1,$ not $a+b=e.$

As for the differentiability condition, you can proceed for the left differential like you did for the right one, but using that now, $f(e)=1:$
$$\lim_{h \to 0^{-}} \frac{f(e+h)-f(e)}h=\lim_{h \to 0^{-}} \frac{\ln^4(e+h)-1}h=\dots$$
However, a simpler method is to differentiate as usual at $e$ the two (now both continuous) functions respectively defined on $(0,e]$ and on $[e,+\infty),$ which are both restrictions of smooth functions on $(0,+\infty).$ You thus get for instance:
$$f'_{\rm left}(e)=4\ln^3(e)\frac1e=\frac4e.$$
Beware to compute it directly like this, and not as the limit of $f'(x)$ as $x\to e^-,$ which would be true also but would require some additional argument.

Conclusion: the two conditions are
$$ae+b=1,\quad\frac4e=a$$
hence the solution is
$$a=\frac4e,\quad b=-3.$$

Comment: thank you very much, but why do I need to beware to compute it directly? In this question first of all I demand that the function will be Continuous at x=e and thus make it Continuous at its domain, after I've done this only then can I compute the derivative directly?

Comment: For the second question: yes, whatever method you choose to compute the derivative. For the first question: I see 3 methods: yours is the most direct, mine is the quickest, and the third one is a little longer and above all requires a technical lemma: if a function $f$ is continuous at $a$ and if $\lim_{a^-}f'(a)=\ell$ then $f$ admits at $a$ a left derivative, which is equal to $\ell.$

Comment: Why these 2 downvotes today, all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1):

The First equation is wrong, for continuity you need that $f(e^-) =f(e^+) $, which implies that $ae+b=1$. Now for $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(\ln(e+h))^4-ae-b}{et},$$ use that $ae+b=1$, and $\ln(e+h) =\ln(e(1+h/e))=\ln e+\ln(1+t)\sim 1+t, $ where $t=h/e$. Using that you get the following limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(1+t)^4-ae-b}{et}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(1+t)^4-1}{et}=4/e,$$ so we get from continuity that $ae+b=1$ and from differentiability that $a=4/e$, so $b=-3$.

Comment: The final limit is not $0$ but $\frac4e.$