# Function by parts and derivative by definition

Tags: limits, derivatives

Given the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
3x^2-2x+4, & \forall x\geq2 \\
10x+5, & \forall x<2
\end{cases}$$

I have to evaluate
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$
at $x_0=2$. However, I'm not totally sure about it. Do I evaluate the limit above for the "two" functions, then take $x=2$ and see if they are equal?

Comment: Simply notice that $f$ is not left continuous (hence not differentiable) at $x_0.$ For a more interesting example, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4711870/386889

Comment: @AnneBauval but I have to evaluate the limits.

Comment: Note that in this case for $x>2$ we have $f'(x)=6x-2$ with $f(2)=10$ and for $x<2$ we have $f'(x)=10$ but as noticed $f$ is not continuous at $x=2$, therefore it is not differentiable.

Comment: @user these calculations of $f'(x)$ for $x\ne2$ are off topic.

Comment: @mvfs314 You don't have to evaluate the limitS, but the limiT. And my first sentence above proves that this limit does not exist. (This is the definition of $f'(x_0)$.)

Comment: @AnneBauval Indeed, I mean even if the right and left limit are equal, we can't conclude since the function is not continuous at $x=2$.

Comment: @user I did not notice that the left and right limits of $f'$ at $x_0$ were equal. I understand now your point of view, but the delightful  theorem you are alluding to, besides being indeed not usable here, might obscure the OP's thoughts. "Too much info kills the info."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed $f$ is not continuous at $x=2$, since $f(2)= 12$ but $\lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x)=25$, therefore it is not differentiable at that point.

If we want proceed by definition, we need to consider two cases

1. $x\ge2$

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{3(2+h)^2-2(2+h)+4-12}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}10+3h=10$$

2. $x<2$

$$\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{10(2+h)+5-12}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-} 10+\frac{13}h=-\infty$$